# Is there any way to change the PART style to have black background?

Tags: titlesec

First the MWE

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\partfont}{}

%% \titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
            {\pagecolor{black}\color{white}\fontsize{60}{80}\selectfont\partfont}
            {\fontsize{36}{42}\selectfont\normalfont \textbf{ \thepart}}  % 
            {0em}
            {}[\nopagecolor] % problem!
\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}

\usepackage{geometry}[b5paper, margin=1.25in]

\begin{document}
\part{Awesome Part}
\chapter{The Ego and its Own}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

Now: I want the **part** page color to be black, with white letters. If I don't use the `after-code` `\nopagecolor`, then the every page is black.
When I use it as in the MWE, the part page is rendered white aswell (so you cannot read the part name because it's white too.

Surprisingly, I don't have to do anything to get black text outside the part page -- despite setting it white and said color change seemingly being global when using `\pagecolor`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delay the `\nopagecolor` until the end of the page:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\partfont}{}

%% \titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
            {\pagecolor{black}\color{white}\fontsize{60}{80}\selectfont\partfont}
            {\fontsize{36}{42}\selectfont\normalfont \textbf{ \thepart}}  % 
            {0em}
            {}[\AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{\nopagecolor}] % problem!
\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}

\usepackage{geometry}[b5paper, margin=1.25in]

\begin{document}
\part{Awesome Part}
\chapter{The Ego and its Own}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very clever, didn't know of these hook commands!

Comment: @Adrian These hooks are a rather new addition to latex, I think they were added sometime around 2020 or 2021. They come in really handy :)